# Where are the setting for "heredoc format style" in PhpStorm 9.0.2

Tags: phpstorm, heredoc

I have something like this:

```
$heredoc = <<< HEREDOC_ID 
some $contents 
HEREDOC_ID;
```

but after formatting it now looks like this:

```
$heredoc 
    = <<< HEREDOC_ID 
some $contents 
HEREDOC_ID;
```

[image]

Where can I set such option? I could not find it in `Editor -> Code Style -> PHP`.

Comment: There is no special settings for "heredoc format style" -- it's definitely some another one. I suggest switching to Default and compare them until you find the one that does it. I personally have never seen anything like that -- it formats normally for me in this regard in both v9 and v10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On PhpStorm 9 and 10, it can be changed by **Assignment statement** -> **Assignment sign on next line** setting on **Wrapping and Braces** tab.

This setting will also affect following code style:

**Off**

```
class Foo
{
    var $numbers = array( "one",
                          "two",
                          "three",
                          "four",
                          "five",
                          "six" );
}
```

**On**

```
class Foo
{
    var $numbers
        = array( "one",
                 "two",
                 "three",
                 "four",
                 "five",
                 "six" );
}
```